# Question about reliability of windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I got a quite long windows batch script. In the middle of it there's a section using appcmd to detect the root path of a site in my IIS. That section runs fine when executed standalone. But when I execute the ***whole*** batch, this section could fail to detect the site path ***once in a while***. I am totally confused by this unreliability issue. Have anyone met this before?

Thanks

### Solution

It seems that there's some delay between a variable declaration and its coming into effect. I changed the order of some part of the batch file and it runs fine so far. I must say, it's still weird.

Comment: What's the rest of that **whole** batch look like?

Comment: I know only two "unreliabilities" of batch, the first are echoing in ascynchron tasks and the second is crashing with LFs in blocks. But as Cody Gray said, we need the code.

Comment: I encountered some similar issue with a long batch script. I assigned some value to a variable and then echo the variable immediately. The value is empty. I just don't know when I can use the variable for sure. It really sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know what type of problem you have in your unknown code, I can only show the known unpredicable or random behaviour in batch-files.

1- multiple tasks echo of line ends
Sometimes but not always the linefeeds and carriage returns are print as the ASCII-Chars 10/13 (a circle and a note) instead of begin a new line.

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="/second" (
  call :task %2
  goto :eof
)
(call "%~0" /second 1 >con ) | ( call "%~0" /second 2 )
echo END OF TASKS
goto :eof

:task
for /L %%n IN (1,1,10) DO (
    echo This is task%1, output no %%n
    ping -n 2 localhost > nul
)

goto :eof
```

2- Sometimes but not always an expansion of %~^LF crashes, then the command window closes immediatly.

```
@echo off
set critical_content=hello%%~^

echo No crash
for %%a in (1 ) do (
    for %%x in (4) do (
        rem #%critical_content%#
    )
)
```